# when trying to connect to IPFS System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, ipfs

I am trying to upload a file to Ipfs below is my code sample.

```
using (var ipfs = new IpfsClient())
                {
                    await ipfs.Swarm.Peers();
                    IpfsStream inputStream = new IpfsStream(filepath, System.IO.File.OpenRead(filepath));
                    MerkleNode node = await ipfs.Add(inputStream);
                    return Ok(node.Hash);
                }
```

and i am getting error
**System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)**

Any reasons my firewall is turned off so that cant be an issue. Any suggestions.

Is it correct approach to write file on ipfs.

Comment: Shouldn't the `IpfsClient()` have a source address? Otherwise, where is the file being uploaded to?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is giving you the answer. The remote server is denying the connection. Either the connection configuration is wrong at your end, or there's a mechanism at the service end that will only allow an incoming connection from certain places. Check both.